# Creating a union of 2 bezier paths

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I have two bezier paths that i'd like to combine to form a union, so that I can stroke the entire outer shape. In my case, it's a speech bubble with a tail, so although it's not a complex shape it would actually be quite hard to create it using one single path.

There doesn't appear to be a Core Graphics API for creating unions. Am I wrong?

If I'm not, does anyone know of a library that can handle this? I've search GitHub to no avail.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer in case somebody comes along with a library on GitHub, but: No, there is no built-in API for this. The usual hack around it is to stroke and then fill; the fill (with the bubble's background color) covers up the intersecting strokes. Make sure to double your line width, since this will be effectively an outer stroke with half the line width.

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks, that's a workable solution for the time being, although it does require that I pass by draw in context. It would have been nicer to create a shape layer.

Comment: I've also just found this library for NSBezierPath. I imagine that a port to UIBezierPath would be trivial: http://losingfight.com/blog/2011/07/09/how-to-implement-boolean-operations-on-bezier-paths-part-3/

Comment: @tarmes turns out it's now available, hooray!  see the robmayoff answer below also https://mastodon.social/@mayoff/109750596404269990

Answer (score 5):

UIBezierPath does that if you are working with closed shapes.

```
UIBezierPath *firstPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
// build your path

UIBezierPath *secondPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
// build your path

[firstPath appendPath:secondPath];
```

Comment: I've just tried that. The result is that the overlap becomes a hole - so it's not creating a union at all.

Comment: try to reverse the path of the first or second before doing the union:    UIBezierPath *secondPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPath] bezierPathByReversingPath];

Comment: Nope. I've tried every combination (1st + 2nd, 1st + reversed 2nd, reversed 1st + 2nd, 2nd + 1st, ....)

Comment: Are you sure you are creating both paths going in a clockwise direction?

Comment: Actually, they weren't in the same direction. Having fixed that there's no longer any hole at the point of intersection, however the stroke around the intersection remains visible.

Comment: Yeah, this is not a 'union' operation, but rather a 'combine' operation, meaning no parts of the existing paths are removed.  If you stroke the path, you'll see they still exist.  A true 'union' operation takes the outline of the combined paths, discarding any paths that would now be on the inside.  That's what I'm looking for myself.

Comment: This absolutely does not answer the question

Answer (score 4):

If your deployment target is iOS 16 (or macOS 13) or later, you can compute the union of two `CGPath` objects using the [`union`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpath/3994971-union) method, like so:

```
let path1: CGPath = ...
let path2: CGPath = ...
let combo = path1.union(path2)
```

Comment: StackOverflow still shows its value in this GPT era!

Answer (score -2):

In Swift 3 Bezier paths can be unified by:

```
 override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    UIColor.black.setStroke()
    UIColor.red.setFill()

    let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    currentContext?.saveGState() 

    let path = drawTopView()
    path.lineWidth = 5.0
    path.fill()
    path.stroke()

    let middlepath = drawMiddleView()
    middlepath.lineWidth = 2.0
    middlepath.fill()
    middlepath.stroke()

    path.append(middlepath)
    currentContext?.restoreGState()
}
```

Comment: This is drawing. Not getting a union bezier path.

Answer (score -2):

## SwiftUI

```swift
func createView() -> some View {
    let a = Path { path in
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0))
    }
    .stroke(Color.white, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))

    let b = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous)
        .fill(Color.white)
        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
        .position(CGPoint.zero)

    return ZStack {
        a
        b
    }
    .compositingGroup()
    .colorMultiply(Color.red)
}
```

Comment: Not even answering the question. The question is asking how to get a union brazier path, not drawing a shape.