# How to clip UIBezierPath with another UIBezierPath in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, io, mask, uibezierpath

I am building a system of metaballs based on the third example in this blog post http://labs.byhook.com/2011/09/26/vector-metaballs/ in Swift. When I drag the middle metaball, it can the potential to overlap either the right or left metaball (which are stationary). I want to clip the stationary metaball with the 'target' metaball (the one being dragged around). Here's my simplified Metaball class

```
class Metaball: UIView {
    let circlePathLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        circlePathLayer.frame = bounds
        circlePathLayer.lineWidth = 10
        circlePathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        layer.addSublayer(circlePathLayer)
    }

    func circleFrame() -> CGRect {
        let circleFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2*circleRadius, height: 2*circleRadius)
        return circleFrame
    }

    func circlePath() -> UIBezierPath {
        return UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: circleFrame())
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        circlePathLayer.frame = bounds
        circlePathLayer.path = circlePath().CGPath
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do the clipping method in my GameScene class in touchesEnded. Here's the touchesEnded method:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    touching = false
    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInView(self)
    target.center = touchLocation
    var distPoints = dist(leftMetaball.center, pos2: touchLocation)
    // if the distance between touchPoint and the center of the leftmetaball is less than the radius of a metaball x2 (200) they must be overlapping
    if distPoints < 200 {
        // clip leftMetaball path here
    }
}
```

This is what is looks like now when they are intersecting:
[image]

I want the two intersecting circles to form a single odd shaped circle where one bezierpath clips the other to remove the intersecting line.

Comment: "This is what is looks like now" And how is it supposed to look? You have forgotten to explain what the problem is.

Comment: So the two intersecting circles should look like one odd shaped circle with no intersecting line.

Comment: @Kat You can refer :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497703/union-uibezierpaths-rather-than-apend-path/41179791#41179791

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a union of 2 bezier paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178360/creating-a-union-of-2-bezier-paths)

Comment: this IS NOW POSSBLE in 2023.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75415562/294884   suggest close this question to avoid confusion