# Can I union multiple transparent SCNShape objects?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, uibezierpath, arkit

I'm adding multiple transparent SCNShape objects to an ARSCNSceneView scene.

- These shapes are based on user input and should overlap.
- They are all flat shapes made with UIBezierPath on the same plane
- Shapes has to be transparent, so the user can see the camera input behind

The problem is that overlapping shapes are very visible, and I'd like it to show as a single shape - the union of all shapes.

**Failed approaches:**

- Putting it under same node and use parent opacity.
- Merging the UIBezier paths.
- Blend modes
- Transparency modes
- Drawing using primitive triangles instead of UIBezierPath

[image: Wanted vs current results]

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but pretty close.  There's an article reference here that might help,you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178360/creating-a-union-of-2-bezier-paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at [VectorBoolean](https://github.com/lrtitze/Swift-VectorBoolean/blob/master/README.md) which is a swift library to deal with boolean operations like the union you are looking for. I haven't tried it myself but have heard some good things about it.

Comment: Awesome. Union works as expected and it's very easy to use. You simply call `path.fb_union(other)` to get them merged with no overlapping. Unlike native `path.append(other)` behavior.
I'll pull request that repo to add podspec.

Comment: Until pull request approved, you may use the pod from my fork `pod 'VectorBoolean', :git => 'https://github.com/avishic/Swift-VectorBoolean.git'`

Comment: Having some issues with VectorBoolean - on some cases it removes the whole path / create unwanted holes in the union.